go get is always returning: no matching versions for query "upgrade"
This started after I consolidated several repositories and go packages into one repository and package.
Here is the message:
go: github.com/sty-holdings/sharedServices/2024: no matching versions for query "upgrade"
This is a private repository (https://github.com/sty-holdings/sharedServices), and I have ssh and .gitconfig working. In the output, I see git is accessing the correct commit: 10c82f1f829304c0e71e5c8f8bb55fbbb5d63f6c.
This commit has a tag, v2024.1.1, which is also being referenced.
Beyond it not working, I don't understand why the git cat-file is looking for go.mod. There is no go.mod for the commit. The project has a go.mod and I ran go clean -modcache.
Commands I enter:
export GOPRIVATE="github.com/sty-holdingse/*"
ssh-add ~/.ssh/github-sty-holdings

go get -x github.com/sty-holdings/sharedServices/2024

go.mod module statement:
module github.com/sty-holdings/sharedServices/v2024

go 1.22.3

require (
    cloud.google.com/go/firestore v1.17.0...

Here is the verbose output:
# lock /Users/syacko/workspace/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/4938f53211fff6e281807bd1f0c505adf446ab26787deab221be7cb288c460e5.lock
# /Users/syacko/workspace/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/4938f53211fff6e281807bd1f0c505adf446ab26787deab221be7cb288c460e5 for git3 https://github.com/sty-holdings/sharedServices
cd /Users/syacko/workspace/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/4938f53211fff6e281807bd1f0c505adf446ab26787deab221be7cb288c460e5; git ls-remote -q origin
1.352s # cd /Users/syacko/workspace/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/4938f53211fff6e281807bd1f0c505adf446ab26787deab221be7cb288c460e5; git ls-remote -q origin
cd /Users/syacko/workspace/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/4938f53211fff6e281807bd1f0c505adf446ab26787deab221be7cb288c460e5; git tag -l
0.021s # cd /Users/syacko/workspace/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/4938f53211fff6e281807bd1f0c505adf446ab26787deab221be7cb288c460e5; git tag -l
cd /Users/syacko/workspace/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/4938f53211fff6e281807bd1f0c505adf446ab26787deab221be7cb288c460e5; git -c log.showsignature=false log --no-decorate -n1 '--format=format:%H %ct %D' 10c82f1f829304c0e71e5c8f8bb55fbbb5d63f6c --
0.015s # cd /Users/syacko/workspace/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/4938f53211fff6e281807bd1f0c505adf446ab26787deab221be7cb288c460e5; git -c log.showsignature=false log --no-decorate -n1 '--format=format:%H %ct %D' 10c82f1f829304c0e71e5c8f8bb55fbbb5d63f6c --
cd /Users/syacko/workspace/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/4938f53211fff6e281807bd1f0c505adf446ab26787deab221be7cb288c460e5; git -c log.showsignature=false log --no-decorate -n1 '--format=format:%H %ct %D' refs/tags/v2024.1.1 --
0.011s # cd /Users/syacko/workspace/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/4938f53211fff6e281807bd1f0c505adf446ab26787deab221be7cb288c460e5; git -c log.showsignature=false log --no-decorate -n1 '--format=format:%H %ct %D' refs/tags/v2024.1.1 --
cd /Users/syacko/workspace/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/4938f53211fff6e281807bd1f0c505adf446ab26787deab221be7cb288c460e5; git cat-file blob 10c82f1f829304c0e71e5c8f8bb55fbbb5d63f6c:go.mod
0.010s # cd /Users/syacko/workspace/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/4938f53211fff6e281807bd1f0c505adf446ab26787deab221be7cb288c460e5; git cat-file blob 10c82f1f829304c0e71e5c8f8bb55fbbb5d63f6c:go.mod
cd /Users/syacko/workspace/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/4938f53211fff6e281807bd1f0c505adf446ab26787deab221be7cb288c460e5; git for-each-ref --format %(refname) refs/tags --merged 10c82f1f829304c0e71e5c8f8bb55fbbb5d63f6c
0.009s # cd /Users/syacko/workspace/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/4938f53211fff6e281807bd1f0c505adf446ab26787deab221be7cb288c460e5; git for-each-ref --format %(refname) refs/tags --merged 10c82f1f829304c0e71e5c8f8bb55fbbb5d63f6c
cd /Users/syacko/workspace/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/4938f53211fff6e281807bd1f0c505adf446ab26787deab221be7cb288c460e5; git cat-file blob 10c82f1f829304c0e71e5c8f8bb55fbbb5d63f6c:go.mod
0.010s # cd /Users/syacko/workspace/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/4938f53211fff6e281807bd1f0c505adf446ab26787deab221be7cb288c460e5; git cat-file blob 10c82f1f829304c0e71e5c8f8bb55fbbb5d63f6c:go.mod
cd /Users/syacko/workspace/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/4938f53211fff6e281807bd1f0c505adf446ab26787deab221be7cb288c460e5; git cat-file blob 10c82f1f829304c0e71e5c8f8bb55fbbb5d63f6c:go.mod
0.008s # cd /Users/syacko/workspace/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/4938f53211fff6e281807bd1f0c505adf446ab26787deab221be7cb288c460e5; git cat-file blob 10c82f1f829304c0e71e5c8f8bb55fbbb5d63f6c:go.mod
cd /Users/syacko/workspace/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/4938f53211fff6e281807bd1f0c505adf446ab26787deab221be7cb288c460e5; git -c log.showsignature=false log --no-decorate -n1 '--format=format:%H %ct %D' 10c82f1f8293 --
0.009s # cd /Users/syacko/workspace/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/4938f53211fff6e281807bd1f0c505adf446ab26787deab221be7cb288c460e5; git -c log.showsignature=false log --no-decorate -n1 '--format=format:%H %ct %D' 10c82f1f8293 --
cd /Users/syacko/workspace/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/4938f53211fff6e281807bd1f0c505adf446ab26787deab221be7cb288c460e5; git cat-file blob 10c82f1f829304c0e71e5c8f8bb55fbbb5d63f6c:2024/go.mod
0.009s # cd /Users/syacko/workspace/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/4938f53211fff6e281807bd1f0c505adf446ab26787deab221be7cb288c460e5; git cat-file blob 10c82f1f829304c0e71e5c8f8bb55fbbb5d63f6c:2024/go.mod
cd /Users/syacko/workspace/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/4938f53211fff6e281807bd1f0c505adf446ab26787deab221be7cb288c460e5; git for-each-ref --format %(refname) refs/tags --merged 10c82f1f829304c0e71e5c8f8bb55fbbb5d63f6c
0.009s # cd /Users/syacko/workspace/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/4938f53211fff6e281807bd1f0c505adf446ab26787deab221be7cb288c460e5; git for-each-ref --format %(refname) refs/tags --merged 10c82f1f829304c0e71e5c8f8bb55fbbb5d63f6c
cd /Users/syacko/workspace/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/4938f53211fff6e281807bd1f0c505adf446ab26787deab221be7cb288c460e5; git fetch -f origin 'refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*' 'refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*'
1.477s # cd /Users/syacko/workspace/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/4938f53211fff6e281807bd1f0c505adf446ab26787deab221be7cb288c460e5; git fetch -f origin 'refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*' 'refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*'
cd /Users/syacko/workspace/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/4938f53211fff6e281807bd1f0c505adf446ab26787deab221be7cb288c460e5; git for-each-ref --format %(refname) refs/tags --merged 10c82f1f829304c0e71e5c8f8bb55fbbb5d63f6c
0.019s # cd /Users/syacko/workspace/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/4938f53211fff6e281807bd1f0c505adf446ab26787deab221be7cb288c460e5; git for-each-ref --format %(refname) refs/tags --merged 10c82f1f829304c0e71e5c8f8bb55fbbb5d63f6c
cd /Users/syacko/workspace/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/4938f53211fff6e281807bd1f0c505adf446ab26787deab221be7cb288c460e5; git cat-file blob 10c82f1f829304c0e71e5c8f8bb55fbbb5d63f6c:go.mod
0.011s # cd /Users/syacko/workspace/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/4938f53211fff6e281807bd1f0c505adf446ab26787deab221be7cb288c460e5; git cat-file blob 10c82f1f829304c0e71e5c8f8bb55fbbb5d63f6c:go.mod
go: github.com/sty-holdings/sharedServices/2024: no matching versions for query "upgrade"



The error message "go: github.com/sty-holdings/sharedServices/2024: no matching versions" and the "go get -x github.com/sty-holdings/sharedServices/2024" use "/2024" but the module declaration "module github.com/sty-holdings/sharedServices/v2024" are different, the module correctly has a "v" before the version. --> Likely just a typo, forgot the v?

Thank you, Volker. Sometimes, I'm so close to something that I can't see the tree in the forest.
